# Error while installing cx_Oracle on windows

Tags: python-2.7, cx-oracle

I am trying to install cx_Oracle module of python in my windows.
I keep getting error below mentioned error: cannot locate an Oracle software installation

What kind of Oracle software I need to make cx_Oracle module work?

## ---------------------------------------------------------------------

```
C:\Users\ndhaka.ORADEV>pip install cx_Oracle
Downloading/unpacking cx-Oracle
Running setup.py (path:c:\users\ndhaka~1.ora\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_ndhaka\cx-Oracle\setup.py) egg_info for package cx-Oracle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "c:\users\ndhaka~1.ora\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_ndhaka\cx-Oracle\setup.py", line 135,in <module>
    raise DistutilsSetupError("cannot locate an Oracle software " \
distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate an Oracle software installation
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "", line 17, in

File "c:\users\ndhaka~1.ora\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_ndhaka\cx-Oracle\setup.py", line 135, in

```
raise DistutilsSetupError("cannot locate an Oracle software " \
```

distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate an Oracle software installation

---

Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\ndhaka~1.ora\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_ndhaka\cx-Oracle
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\ndhaka.ORADEV\pip\pip.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need Oracle client installed on your machine, because cx_Oracle is just a bridge between Python and the Oracle Client.
I had the same problem and solved my issue by installing instant client from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html)
Please make sure to install the compatible version(32 or 64 bit) to your system

Follow all the steps from this link and you will have cx_Oracle module installed perfectly in your machine. [link](http://pyboys.com/configuring-cx_oracle-accessing-oracle-python/)

Comment: The second like is broken, @Learner.